# css target IE and Microsoft Edge

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

What is the proper way to target IE and Microsoft Edge to apply for specific css?

This is my general css:

```
.details-list {
    font-size: 13px;
    font-style: italic;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

so, lets say that I want to increase font-size only for Microssft Edge and IE.

What is the preferable way to do say(sass is set up- if that helps)?

Any help is welcome!

Comment: Use a script and add class to body, script should look like `if (document.documentMode || /Edge/.test(navigator.userAgent)){$('body').addClass('edge-ie')}`, than you can control font size or anything else via CSS, as `.edge-ie .details-list { font-size: 15px; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browser-specific CSS should usually be avoided, but if your really need to, you're having various possibilities. These should be the most common ones:

1. use conditional comments in the html to target specific IE-versions:
   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx
2. use css hacks by writing syntactically wrong CSS, which is (due to autocorrection) still applied in some browsers/versions. 
   http://browserhacks.com/ is a quite good collection for this
3. Use JavaScript to set a CSS-Class like `is-internet-explorer`, which is then used in the css to target only such browsers. As userAgent evaluation is quite difficult and browsers often pretend to be another browser, you should use a JavaScript-Library for this tedious task (e.g. https://github.com/DamonOehlman/detect-browser)
4. Use some Server-Side Logic to deliver an extra CSS-Filer or set an extra class. This is basically the same as #3, but on the server side.

Answer (score 2):

If there is a specific CSS statement you are looking for (like `object-fit:cover`), use feature detection. This has a few benefits, including also working if the browser implements the property down the line.

```css
@supports (object-fit:cover) {
    .element {
        height: 100%;
        object-fit:cover;
    }
}
```

Otherwise you can use CSS Hacks, here is a SASS mixin for that:

```
/**
    Applies for all Internet Explorer and Edge versions
**/
@mixin worstBrowsers() {

    /* all IE versions <= 11 */
    @media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
        @content;
    }

    /* all edge versions */
    @supports (-ms-ime-align:auto) {
        @content;
    }

}


.element {
    @include worstBrowsers {
        font-size: .6em;
    }
}
```